# How to make switch case button in swiftUI with action and title

Tags: swift, loops, swiftui, switch-statement, case

I want to make a button list with different actions in the switch case method in swiftUI.

```
    struct dashboard: View{
        var categoriesText = ["My Orders", "Payments", "Settings", "Password"]
        var categoriesImage = ["wallet.pass", "trophy", "gearshape", "lock.circle"]
        
        var body: some View{
            VStack{
                ForEach(0..<categoriesImage.count) { i in
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink {
                            SettingView()
                                .navigationBarHidden(true)
                            
                        } label: {
                            HStack{
                                HStack{
                                    Image(systemName: categoriesImage[i])
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(minWidth: 30 ,maxWidth: 30, minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 35)
                                        .padding(15)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .background(){
                                            Rectangle()
                                                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                        }
                                        .padding(.horizontal,10)
                                    
                                    VStack{
                                        Text(categoriesText[i])
                                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                                            .bold()
                                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
                                    }
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(maxWidth: 15, maxHeight: 20)
                                        .bold()
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In above code the buttons are in loop but i want these buttons in switch case with different actions so i will navigate each button to another pages

Comment: How would `switch` functionality help you? What are you trying to achieve that your current code isn't accomplishing?

Comment: All your navigation links opens the same view?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Yes but I want to use each button with different actions

Comment: And what is stopping you, what is the problem with using a switch in your code. Also, we have no idea what you mean with "different actions" and why/how this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @Adam Sir I am making a setting view in which different buttons are in use, and each button navigates a different  view, and some of the buttons are used in functionalities, like log out button, and i want all these buttons in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implements two switches: one for your `NavigationLink`, and one for your `Text` (you had the image names on the buttons instead of descriptions of the `NavigationLink`.)

The code assumes you have separate views for each button. You can change the names to fit what you're doing; I just based the view names on your `categoriesText` array.

I hope this answers your question.

```
struct Dashboard: View {
    let categoriesText = ["My Orders", "Payments", "Settings", "Password"]
    let categoriesImage = ["wallet.pass", "trophy", "gearshape", "lock.circle"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(categoriesImage, id: \.self) { image in
                Button(action: {}) {
                    VStack{
                        NavigationLink {
                            switch image {
                            case "wallet.pass":
                                OrdersView()
                            case "trophy":
                                PaymentsView()
                            case "gearshape":
                                SettingsView()
                            case "lock.circle":
                                PasswordView()
                            }
                        } label: {
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: image)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(minWidth: 30 ,maxWidth: 30, minHeight: 30, maxHeight: 35)
                                        .padding(15)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .background(){
                                            Rectangle()
                                                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                                                .cornerRadius(50)
                                        }
                                        .padding(.horizontal,10)
                                    
                                    VStack{
                                        switch image {
                                        case "wallet.pass":
                                            Text(categoriesText[0])
                                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                                .bold()
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
                                        case "trophy":
                                            Text(categoriesText[1])
                                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                                .bold()
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
                                        case "gearshape":
                                            Text(categoriesText[2])
                                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                                .bold()
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
                                        case "lock.circle":
                                            Text(categoriesText[3])
                                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                                .bold()
                                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                                                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
                                        default:
                                            Text("Unknown")
                                        }
                                                                                }
                                    
                                    Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(maxWidth: 15, maxHeight: 20)
                                        .bold()
                                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                                }
                                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```